# How to fix Acer Aspire 4736z back light brightness control in Ubuntu 13.04?

Tags: brightness, acer, backlight, aspire

A simple way to fix Acer Aspire 4736z back light brightness control problem using hot keys (Fn + Brightness **+-**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up the terminal and type

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find this line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=”quiet splash"
```

Replace the line with this:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
```

Save the changes and close the editor then come back to the terminal and enter the below command to update the GRUB configuration:

```
sudo update-grub
```

**Just reboot the machine.**